# VBA compare two folders to find the differents files

Tags: vba, directory, createobject

I have 2 folders **textFiles** & **excelFiles**, They have the same filename but with different extensions (for textFiles = .txt  & excelFiles = .xlsx), 
I write a code, to find if a file in textFiles doesn't exist in excelFiles to call a function who create it.

```
Sub LookForNew()
Dim dTxt As String
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filsTxt = fso.GetFolder("C:\txtFiles").Files
Set filsExcel = fso.GetFolder("C:\excelFiles").Files
Set oFileExcel = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set tFileExl = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set oFileExl = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each fil In filsTxt
  dTxt = fil.Name
    For Each exl In filsExcel
       oFileExcel = exl.Name
       oFileExl = Split(oFileExcel, ".")
       tFileExl = oFileExl(0)
        Next exl
        If Not (tFileExl.Exists(dTxt)) Then
           ' Call function
        Else
        MsgBox "No more files to convert"
        End If
Next fil
Set fso = Nothing
```

End Sub

But the field "oFileExcel" in my code doesn't return an Dictionary but a string
Help plz

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a value the way you did `oFileExcel = exl.Name`, you need to use `oFileExcel.Add = exl.Name`.

Have a look at the documentation of [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx):

```
Dim d                   'Create a variable
Set d = CreateObject(Scripting.Dictionary)
d.Add "a", "Athens"     'Add some keys and items
d.Add "b", "Belgrade"
d.Add "c", "Cairo"
...
```